# How to silence catkin_make output regarding EusLisp

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I catkin_make I get all this unnecessary output like:

"set ARCHDIR to Linux64
use the location of executables to set EUSDIR
set EUSDIR to /opt/ros/hydro/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus"

after every single object is compiled.

How do I silence this?

Thanks
Arjun

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192336/how-to-silence-catkin_make-output-regarding-euslisp/) by [agmenon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4821/agmenon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a complete answer but I suppose one or more packages in your `%CATKIN_WS%/src` refer to `euslisp`. So just to silence it you can temporarily move that package out of the `src` directory. You may determine this by grep etc.:

```
$ grep -r 'euslisp' %CATKIN_WS%/src
$ ack-grep -ai 'euslisp' %CATKIN_WS%/src
```

For a permanent solution, you might want to open a ticket at the issue trackers of the packages you evacuated in the process above.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0